# jQuery Pop Window - Menu/Image Design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I would like to design something like the photo I placed above, it gives the basic idea of what I am trying to accomplish. I think something like this would allow the users to select based on the appearance of the plates (and category).

Also, it shows the user the prices up front and allows users to browse the different plates. I also want where if the user clicks the plate they can see the plate in full size.

The gray boxes in my design represent the images for the plates and undderneath I put the license name, and it's price.

What I had come up with is a combination drop down but I am trying to figure something more like this pop up window instead. Ill have to radio buttons ( Yes / No )if yes the pop up window like the image appears if no nothing happens except clears the price if a plate was already chosen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/j585zy0y/4/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    // When the header for the custom drop-down is clicked
    $(".selectHeader").click(function() {

        // cache the actual dropdown scroll container
        var dropdown = $(this).parent().find(".drop_down_scroll_container");

        // Toggle the visibility on click
        if (dropdown.is(":visible")) {
            dropdown.slideUp();
            $(this).parent().find(".dropdown-subcategory").fadeOut();
        } else {
            dropdown.slideDown();
        }

    });



 // When a top-level menu item is hovered, decide if its
 // coorespnding submenu should be visible or hidden
    $(".drop_down_scroll_container span").hover(

        // hover on
        function() {

            // Remove the "highlighted class from all other options
            $(this).parent().find("span").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("highlighted").addClass("selected");

            // Get the index of the hovered span
            var index = $(this).index();

            // Use the hovered index to reveal the 
            // dropdown-subcategory of the same index
            var subcategorydiv = $(this).parent().parent().find(".dropdown-subcategory").eq(index);
            hideallSubmenusExceptMenuAtIndex($(this).parent().parent(), index);
            subcategorydiv.slideDown();
        },

        // hover off
        function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("highlighted")) {
                var index = $(this).index();
                var subcategorydiv = $(this).parent().parent().find(".dropdown-subcategory").eq(index);
                subcategorydiv.slideUp();
            }
    });

 // Hide all submenu items except for the submenu item at _index
 // This will hide any of the previously opened submenu items
    function hideallSubmenusExceptMenuAtIndex(formElement, _index) {
        formElement.find(".dropdown-subcategory").each(
            function(index) {
                if (_index != index) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        );
    }

 // When any menu item is hovered
    $("span").hover(
        function() {
            $(".hoveredOver").text($(this).text());
        },
        function() {
            $(".hoveredOver").text("");
        }
    );


    // When a sub-menu option is clicked
    $(".dropdown-subcategory span").click(function() {
        $(".dropdown-subcategory span").removeClass("selected");
        $(".clickedOption").text($(this).text());
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".selectHeader").text($(this).text());
        closeDropDown($(this).parent().parent());
        showSpecialPlateModal($(this).text(), $(this).attr("data-image"), $(this).attr("data-price"), $(this).attr("data-code"));
    });

    // Close the dropdowns contained in divToSearch
    function closeDropDown(divToSearch) {
        divToSearch.find(".drop_down_scroll_container").fadeOut();
        divToSearch.find(".dropdown-subcategory").fadeOut();
    };
 
    // Populate and Launch the bootstrap Modal Dialog Specialty Plates 
    function showSpecialPlateModal(name, image, price, code) {
   $('#modal_special').find('.modal-body')
  .html('<h2>' + name + '</h2>')
  .append('<br/>Special Plate Code: <span class="code">' + code + '</span><br/>')
  .append('<p>Image will go here:</p><br/><img alt="" src="' + image + '"/>')
  .append('<br/><br/>Price: <span class="price">' + price + '</span><br/>')
  .end().modal('show');
    }

    // When the modal "Accept" button is pressed
    $('.accept').on('click', function() {
  var modal_element = $('#modal_special');
  var name = modal_element.find("h2").text();
  var price = modal_element.find("span.price").text();
  var code = modal_element.find("span.code").text();
  $('#modal_special').modal('hide').end(alert(name + " was selected for a price of " + price));
    });

});
```

```css
#dropdown {
width:175px;
height:200px;
position:relative;
font-size:12px;
}

.selectHeader {
height:20px;
width:100%;
background-color:#fff;
border:solid thin #ccc;
color:#000;
cursor:pointer;
padding:0 3px;
}

#dropdown span {
display:block;
background-color:#fff;
color:#000;
cursor:pointer;
font-weight:400;
font:inherit;
padding:0 3px;
}

#dropdown span:hover {
background-color:#1C7BD2;
color:#fff;
}

.drop_down_scroll_container {
display:none;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:scroll;
border:solid thin #ccc;
}

.dropdown-subcategory {
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:100%;
z-index:100;
width:100%;
border:solid thin #ccc;
}

.selected {
background-color:#1C7BD2!important;
color:#fff!important;
}

.boxshadow {
box-shadow:0 2px 7px 1px rgba(119,119,119,0.68);
-moz-box-shadow:0 2px 7px 1px rgba(119,119,119,0.68);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 7px 1px rgba(119,119,119,0.68);
}

.hoveredOver,.clickedOption {
font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
You are hovered over: <span class="hoveredOver"></span><br/>
You have clicked on option: <span class="clickedOption"></span>

<br/><br/>

<!-- CUSTOM DROP DOWN EXAMPLE -->

<div id="dropdown" class="specialtyPlatesCategories">
    
    <div class="selectHeader">Click to Select Plates:</div>
    
    <!-- THIS IS WHERE YOU WILL PUT YOUR TOP-LEVEL OPTIONS -->
    <div class="drop_down_scroll_container"> 
 <span>Environment / Wildlife</span> 
 <span>Community Interest</span> 
 <span>Health Interest</span> 
 <span>Family / Kids</span> 
 <span>American Heroes</span> 
 <span>Professional Sports</span> 
 <span>Collegiate</span> 
 <span>Motorcycle</span> 
 </div> 

 <!-- THIS IS WHERE YOU WILL PUT YOUR SUB-LEVEL OPTIONS --> 
 <div id="Environment / Wildlife_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory"> 
 <span data-code="ANR" data-image="/images/img/AnimalFriend.png" data-price="30">Animal Friend</span> 
 <span data-code="QCR" data-image="/images/img/Aquaculture.png" data-price="30">Aquaculture</span> 
 <span data-code="CER" data-image="/images/img/ProtectOurOceans.png" data-price="30">Protect Our Oceans</span> 
 <span data-code="CWR" data-image="/images/img/ConserveWildlife.png" data-price="30">Conserve Wildlife</span> 
 <span data-code="DFR" data-image="/images/img/DiscoverFloridaOceans.png" data-price="30">Discover Florida Oceans</span> 
 <span data-code="ERR" data-image="/images/img/EvergladesRiverofGrass.png" data-price="25">Everglades River of Grass</span> 
 <span data-code="FVR" data-image="/images/img/FishFlorida.png" data-price="27">Fish Florida</span> 
 <span data-code="INR" data-image="/images/img/IndianRiverLagoon.png" data-price="20">Indian River Lagoon</span> 
 <span data-code="LBR" data-image="/images/img/LargemouthBass.png" data-price="30">Largemouth Bass</span> 
 <span data-code="PAR" data-image="/images/img/ProtectthePanther.png" data-price="30">Protect the Panther</span> 
 <span data-code="PFR" data-image="/images/img/ProtectFloridaSprings.png" data-price="30">Protect Florida Springs</span> 
 <span data-code="WHR" data-image="/images/img/ProtectFloridaWhales.png" data-price="30">Protect Florida Whales</span> 
 <span data-code="POR" data-image="/images/img/ProtectOurReefs.png" data-price="30">Protect Our Reefs</span> 
 <span data-code="PWR" data-image="/images/img/ProtectWildDolphins.png" data-price="25">Protect Wild Dolphins</span> 
 <span data-code="SZR" data-image="/images/img/SaveOurSeas.png" data-price="30">Save Our Seas</span> 
 <span data-code="MTR" data-image="/images/img/SavetheManatee.png" data-price="30">Save the Manatee</span> 
 <span data-code="FBR" data-image="/images/img/SaveWildFlorida.png" data-price="30">Florida Biodiversity - Save Wild Florida</span> 
 <span data-code="STR" data-image="/images/img/SeaTurtle.png" data-price="28">Sea Turtle</span> 
 <span data-code="SNR" data-image="/images/img/WildlifeFoundationofFlorida.png" data-price="30">Wildlife Foundation of Florida</span> 
 <span data-code="FFR" data-image="/images/img/StateWildflower.png" data-price="20">State Wildflower</span> 
 <span data-code="TAR" data-image="/images/img/TampaBayEstuary.png" data-price="20">Tampa Bay Estuary</span> 
 <span data-code="TCR" data-image="/images/img/TreesareCool.png" data-price="30">Trees are Cool</span> 
 </div> 

 <div id="Community Interest_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory"> 
 <span data-code="AER" data-image="/images/img/AgriculturalEducation.png" data-price="30">Agricultural Education</span> 
 <span data-code="AGR" data-image="/images/img/Agriculture.png" data-price="25">Agriculture</span> 
 <span data-code="CLR" data-image="/images/img/ChallengerColumbia.png" data-price="30">Challenger/Columbia</span> 
 <span data-code="CFR" data-image="/images/img/CorrectionsFoundation.png" data-price="30">Corrections Foundation</span> 
 <span data-code="ESR" data-image="/images/img/EndlessSummer.png" data-price="30">Endless Summer</span> 
 <span data-code="ARR" data-image="/images/img/FloridaArts.png" data-price="25">Florida Arts</span> 
 <span data-code="HFR" data-image="/images/img/FloridaHorsePark.png" data-price="30">Florida Horse Park (Discover Florida's Horses)</span> 
 <span data-code="FYR" data-image="/images/img/FloridaSheriffsYouthRanches.png" data-price="30">Florida Sheriffs Youth Ranches</span> 
 <span data-code="TNR" data-image="/images/img/FloridaTennis.png" data-price="30">Florida Tennis</span> 
 <span data-code="ORR" data-image="/images/img/FraternalOrderofPolice.png" data-price="30">Fraternal Order of Police</span> 
 <span data-code="FQR" data-image="/images/img/FreeMasonry.png" data-price="30">Free Masonry</span> 
 <span data-code="GOR" data-image="/images/img/GolfCapital.png" data-price="30">Golf Capital</span> 
 <span data-code="HAR" data-image="/images/img/HomeOwnership.png" data-price="30">Home Ownership</span> 
 <span data-code="HRR" data-image="/images/img/HorseCountry.png" data-price="30">Horse Country</span> 
 <span data-code="IMR" data-image="/images/img/Imagine.png" data-price="30">Imagine</span> 
 <span data-code="IGR" data-image="/images/img/InGodWeTrust.png" data-price="30">In God We Trust</span> 
 <span data-code="LHR" data-image="/images/img/VisitOurLights.png" data-price="30">Lighthouse Association - Visit Our Lights</span> 
 <span data-code="LDR" data-image="/images/img/LivetheDream.png" data-price="30">Live the Dream</span> 
 <span data-code="AHR" data-image="/images/img/PoliceAthleticLeague.png" data-price="25">Police Athletic League</span> 
 <span data-code="SAR" data-image="/images/img/SharetheRoad.png" data-price="20">Share the Road</span> 
 <span data-code="SPR" data-image="/images/img/SpecialOlympics.png" data-price="20">Special Olympics</span> 
 <span data-code="EDR" data-image="/images/img/SupportEducation.png" data-price="25">Support Education</span> 
 <span data-code="SYR" data-image="/images/img/SupportSoccer.png" data-price="30">Support Soccer</span> 
 <span data-code="SOR" data-image="/images/img/USOlympic.png" data-price="20">US Olympic</span> 

 </div> 

 <div id="Health Interest_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory"> 
 <span data-code="RXR" data-image="/images/img/AmericanRedCross.png" data-price="30">American Red Cross</span> 
 <span data-code="CSR" data-image="/images/img/ChooseLife.png" data-price="25">Choose Life</span> 
 <span data-code="DOR" data-image="/images/img/DonateOrgans.png" data-price="30">Donate Organs</span> 
 <span data-code="CRR" data-image="/images/img/EndBreastCancer.png" data-price="30">End Breast Cancer</span> 
 <span data-code="HOR" data-image="/images/img/Hospice.png" data-price="30">Hospice</span> 
 <span data-code="MJR" data-image="/images/img/MoffittCancerCenter.png" data-price="25">Moffitt Cancer Center</span> 
 <span data-code="VIR" data-image="/images/img/StateofVision.png" data-price="30">State of Vision</span> 
 <span data-code="SDR" data-image="/images/img/StopHeartDisease.png" data-price="30">Stop Heart Disease</span> 
 <span data-code="ASR" data-image="/images/img/SupportAutismPrograms.png" data-price="30">Support Autism Programs</span> 
 </div> 
 <div id="Family / Kids_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory"> 
 <span data-code="SCR" data-image="/images/img/BoyScouts.png" data-price="25">Boy Scouts</span> 
 <span data-code="CAR" data-image="/images/img/StopChildAbuse.png" data-price="30">Stop Child Abuse</span> 
 <span data-code="FJR" data-image="/images/img/FamilyFirst.png" data-price="30">Family First</span> 
 <span data-code="FUR" data-image="/images/img/FamilyValues.png" data-price="30">Family Values</span> 
 <span data-code="CHR" data-image="/images/img/InvestinChildren.png" data-price="25">Invest in Children</span> 
 <span data-code="KKR" data-image="/images/img/KeepKidsDrugFree.png" data-price="30">Keep Kids Drug Free</span> 
 <span data-code="KDR" data-image="/images/img/KidsDeserveJustice.png" data-price="30">Kids Deserve Justice</span> 
 <span data-code="LKR" data-image="/images/img/LaurensKids.png" data-price="30">Lauren's Kids</span> 
 <span data-code="PMR" data-image="/images/img/ParentsMakeaDifference.png" data-price="30">Parents Make a Difference</span> 
 </div> 

 <div id="American Heroes_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory"> 
 <span data-code="SPRT01" data-image="" data-price="34.00">Sports 01</span> 
 <span data-code="SPRT02" data-image="" data-price="35.00">Sports 02</span> 
 <span data-code="SPRT03" data-image="" data-price="36.00">Sports 03</span> 
 </div> 

 <div id="Professional Sports_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory"> 
 <span data-code="MAR" data-image="/images/img/FloridaMarlins.png" data-price="30">Florida Marlins</span> 
 <span data-code="PTR" data-image="/images/img/FloridaPanthers.png" data-price="30">Florida Panthers</span> 
 <span data-code="JJR" data-image="/images/img/JacksonvilleJaguars.png" data-price="30">Jacksonville Jaguars</span> 
 <span data-code="MDR" data-image="/images/img/MiamiDolphins.png" data-price="30">Miami Dolphins</span> 
 <span data-code="MHR" data-image="/images/img/MiamiHeat.png" data-price="30">Miami Heat</span> 
 <span data-code="OMR" data-image="/images/img/OrlandoMagic.png" data-price="30">Orlando Magic</span> 
 <span data-code="BBR" data-image="/images/img/TampaBayBucs.png" data-price="30">Tampa Bay Bucs</span> 
 <span data-code="DRR" data-image="/images/img/TampaBayRays.png" data-price="30">Tampa Bay Rays</span> 
 <span data-code="TBR" data-image="/images/img/TampaBayLightning.png" data-price="30">Tampa Bay Lightning</span> 
 <span data-code="NZR" data-image="/images/img/Nascar.png" data-price="30">Nascar</span> 
 </div> 
 <div id="Collegiate_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory"> 
 <span data-code="ENV01" data-image="" data-price="31.00">Environment 01</span> 
 <span data-code="ENV02" data-image="" data-price="32.00">Environment 02</span> 
 <span data-code="ENV03" data-image="" data-price="33.00">Environment 03</span> 
 </div> 

 <div id="Motorcycle_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory"> 
 <span data-code="MYR" data-image="/images/img/MotorcycleSpecialty.png" data-price="22">Motorcycle Specialty</span> 
 <span data-code="MUR" data-image="/images/img/MotorcylceUnderage.png" data-price="22">Motorcylce Underage</span> 
 </div>




<!-- BOOTSTRAP MODAL FOR SPECIAL PLATES -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_special" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
         </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Specialty Plate</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary accept">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have not understand where you whant to located radio buttons. Your script work fine, I created similar plugin for one my app but I do not understand your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I see what you are trying to do, you are trying to create a fancy selection window, instead of trying to use a custom "dropdown" menu. So I rose to the challenge and created a mockup for you.

### [YOU CAN REVIEW THE MOCKUP DEMO ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qhaojLo0/2/)

The basic idea is was converting your custom dropdown into a custom application.

**First, I converted all your `<optgroup></optgroup>` to this format:**

```
<div class="licenseSection" id="licenseSection0">
    <!-- buttons for this section go here -->
</div>
```

**And each one of the `<option></option>` tags were converted to this:**

```
<div class="licenseButton" data-price="30" data-code="2" data-name="Aquaculture">
    <div class="selectedLicenseFlag"></div>
    <div class="licenseImage">
        <img src="/images/img/Aquaculture.png" alt="Aquaculture" />
    </div>
    <div class="licenseInfoName">Aquaculture</div>
    <div class="licenseInfoPrice">$30</div>
</div>
```

**And now, since every "category" is now in it's own `licenseSection` div, it was just a matter of getting jQuery to show or hide the appropriate sections. Like this:**

```
$("ul.SL_category_buttons li").click(function(){

    var buttonIndex = $(this).index();

    // Handle the button highlighting if the button is already selected
    if ($(this).hasClass("selectedLicenseCategory") == false){
        $("ul.SL_category_buttons li").removeClass("selectedLicenseCategory");
        $("ul.SL_category_buttons li").removeClass("hoverLicenseCategory");
        $(this).addClass("selectedLicenseCategory");

        // Reveal the category options
        revealLicenseCategoryPageAtIndex(buttonIndex);  
    }   
});

function revealLicenseCategoryPageAtIndex(index){
    $(".licenseSection").fadeOut().end(
        $(".licenseSection").eq(index).delay(300).fadeIn()
    );
}
```

**Some of the features of this demo include:**

- The price of the license appears when the license thumbnail is
  hovered.
- The selected license appears below the license picker so the user can
  keep review before accepting
- The entire modal window is a bootstrap component, so it can be easily
  opened and closed.

## How to integrate this picker into your application:

**1. Launching the modal window:**

```
// Option #01
$('#modal_special').modal('show');

// Option #02
// Assign a button with the id of launchLicenseModalSelect to reach this code
$("#launchLicenseModalSelect").click(function(){
    $('#modal_special').modal('show');  
});
```

**1. Getting the user-selected data:**

This application sets a variable called `selectedLicense` to keep track of which license was selected, so when the user clicks the "Accept" button on the form, you can do anything you want with the `selectedLicense` object (update your UI, update your calculations, etc):

```
$(".accept").click(function(){
    // Hide the modal
    $('#modal_special').modal('hide');

    // Access the selectedLicense object.
    console.log("The following license was selected:", selectedLicense);
    alert("The following license was accepted:\n\n"+selectedLicense.name+" $"+selectedLicense.price);
});
```

So that is basic idea. [Please review the JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qhaojLo0/2/), and feel free to ask any questions you might have.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Make sure that you have all the html from the fiddle pasted into your file, then be sure to import the css from the fiddle into your css file (or style section), lastly, make sure the id of your button is `launchLicenseModalSelect` so something like <span id="launchLicenseModalSelect">BUTTON TEXT HERE</span>`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "main page", but it sounds like you got it working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64253/discussion-between-radiovisual-and-vicki).